# The Packets Transfer from Kafka connect to AWS S3 bucket is Slow. How to increase the throughput

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Am using Kafka Connect S3 to push the records to AWS s3 bucket, we are using timebasedpartioner for the s3.sink.properties and we are noticing only 10 records per second. Please guide in increasing the throughput.

Comment: You'll need to dig into some metrics. What's the rate at which messages arrive in the topic? How many partitions? How many Kafka Connect workers? What's the network utilisation on your Kafka Connect worker(s)? CPU and memory utilisation? etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your question mentions "packet transfer", but given the max size of a Kafka record defaulting to 1MB, and in a 10MB file over the network, that could be a lot of packets...

Ultimately, network is not the only factor here. You need to consider your ISP rates at the very least (assuming Connect is not running in AWS, which it should if you want to save $$ on VPC/S3 ingest fees), then look how much data the producers are actually sending to the topic.

Once determined, since you use the timebased partitioner, you have not mentioned your time period or flush size or flush interval (scheduled or not). If you have a daily partition, and the flush settings are ridicuously high, then of course you'll have little to no data immeadiately in S3.

You can increase throughput by increasing `comsumer.max.poll.records`, and lowering the flush settings & `s3.part.size`, but first thoughts suggest this is not your issue.